# Need to group records in SQL Server 2012 Query but hitting "field not in aggregate" issue

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I have this query

```
SELECT Count(BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER) AS CountOfSERIALNUMBER,
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q2',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (1,2,3) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q3',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (4,5,6) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q4',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=Format(DateAdd(year,-1,getdate()),'yyyy'),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=Format(DateAdd(year,-1,getdate()),'yyyy'),'Q2','NULL')))))) AS Quarter
FROM BATCHDETAIL INNER JOIN 
(SELECT  Min(BATCHDETAIL.DATEOFPAYMENT) AS FirstPaid, BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER
FROM BATCHDETAIL
GROUP BY BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER) SO
 ON BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER = SO.SERIALNUMBER
WHERE (((BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTTYPE)='Cash'))
GROUP BY IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q2',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (1,2,3) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q3',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (4,5,6) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q4',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())),'Q2','NULL'))))))
HAVING 
(((IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])>7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q2',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (1,2,3) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q3',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (4,5,6) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,Getdate()),'Q4',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (7,8,9) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())),'Q1',
IIf(datepart(month,[FirstPaid])<7 And datepart(month,[FirstPaid]) In (10,11,12) And datepart(year,[FirstPaid])=datepart(year,DateAdd(year,-1,getdate())),'Q2','NULL')))))))<>'Null'));
```

Where I want to group according to the derived Quarter, by using the first date a payment was posted as FirstPaid to get the quarter in the IIF conditions. I am stuck trying to get the grouping without including the FirstPaid field in the Group By which ruins the quarterly grouping, any help gratefully received. This is in SQL Server 2012

Adrian

Comment: It seems that a [FirstPaid] in the month of July will result in a NULL quarter. Is that intentional?

Comment: You have conditions in the query that can never be true, as well as conditions that are redundant. Is your intention to group Q1 this year together with Q1 last year?

Comment: can you not create a CTE with begin and end dates for each quarter, and join to that where FirstPaid between BeginDate and EndDate? Or a temp table or something besides IIf(blahblahblahblah)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to code for a custom calendar in T-SQL.  Without answering this question, check out my article on [SQL Calendar Table](http://rdsrc.us/wcDJC1), which is a demo plus downloadable code on how to create a table that can handle this.

The quarter grouping as you have it defined can be changed in the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Jim Thanks for the try but this is reporting from a database I can't amend, I need to get a count of the serial numbers in the quarter without creating a new table

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to get a count by quarter for everything after 7-1-2014, grouped by quarters this might work for you

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfSERIALNUMBER,
    CASE WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (7,8,9) THEN 'Q1'
         WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (10,11,12) THEN 'Q2'
         WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Q3'
         ELSE 'Q4' END AS Quarter
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATEPART(MONTH,MIN(BATCHDETAIL.DATEOFPAYMENT)) AS FirstPaidMonth,
        BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER
    FROM
        BATCHDETAIL
    WHERE
        BATCHDETAIL.PAYMENTTYPE = 'Cash'
    GROUP BY
        BATCHDETAIL.SERIALNUMBER
    HAVING 
        MIN(BATCHDETAIL.DATEOFPAYMENT) >= 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) >= 7 
                THEN DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 7, 1,0,0,0,0) 
                ELSE DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 1, 7, 1,0,0,0,0)
            END
) t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (7,8,9) THEN 'Q1'
         WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (10,11,12) THEN 'Q2'
         WHEN FirstPaidMonth IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Q3'
         ELSE 'Q4' END
```

You can also create a CTE with the dates you're looking for and their respective quarters and just join to that.

```
;WITH cte (BeginDate, EndDate, [Quarter])
AS (
  SELECT '2014-07-01', '2014-10-01', 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2014-10-01', '2015-01-01', 'Q2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-01-01', '2015-04-01', 'Q3' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-04-01', '2015-07-01', 'Q4' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-07-01', '2015-10-01', 'Q1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2015-10-01', '2016-01-01', 'Q2' 
)  
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfSERIALNUMBER,
    [Quarter]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        cte.[Quarter],
        bd.SERIALNUMBER,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bd.SERIALNUMBER ORDER BY bd.DATEOFPAYMENT) RN
    FROM
        BATCHDETAIL bd
        JOIN cte ON bd.DATEOFPAYMENT >= cte.BeginDate AND bd.DATEOFPAYMENT < cte.EndDate
    WHERE
        bd.PAYMENTTYPE = 'Cash'
    GROUP BY
        cte.[Quarter],  
        bd.SERIALNUMBER,
        bd.DATEOFPAYMENT
    HAVING 
        MIN(bd.DATEOFPAYMENT) >= '07/01/2014'
) t
WHERE t.RN = 1
GROUP BY [Quarter]
```

Comment: Jamie, This is close but I need to check the year as well, the financial year runs July through June so I need the quarters for the current financial year, whenever this is run Thanks for the help

Comment: gotcha.. i'll update the Having in first query to get current financial year.  can there be future dates outside of the current financial year?

Comment: Jamie, your a star, that gives me the current year nicely. Future dates is not possible, just hope they don't ask for more historical dates !